# Как возможно автоматизировать импорт данных из CSV в XML файл?

Tags: python, java, xml, selenium, csv

**Как возможно автоматизировать импорт данных из CSV в XML файл?**
Добрый день, на работе возникла проблема с выгрузкой препаратов, вышедших из оборота, и дабы избавиться от монотонной работы (имеется более 500 точек, по которым надо делать выгрузку), возникла идея автоматизации этой монотонной деятельности.

С сайта МДЛП делается выгрузка .csv файла с данными, с помощью них надо сделать вывод по каждому месту деятельности, и привязанным к ним товарам, вышедшим из оборота

Подскажите, с помощью какого инструмента лучше это сделать? Выгрузку xml файла уже можно будет сделать вручную, нужна именно генерация файла. Есть подобный генератор - https://markirovka-lekarstv.ru/generaciya-shemy-552/, но тут нужно вручную вбивать каждую аптеку и копировать список товаров, хоть и занимает эта работа по минуте, но учитывая более 500 аптек, работа монотонно растягивается на десяток и более часов.

Comment: Pandas пробовали? Там есть чтение csv и вывод в xml

Comment: Сам файл приложите для начала. Так же приложите файл того что должно получиться.